# Cross-compiling debian on Beaglebone green

Tags: debian, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I have beaglebone green with me. I've successfully burnt a debian image to it. I was able to run beaglebone on my host machine (Ubuntu) using ssh. 
But the problem is that the kernel version of debian is quite old and I don't see the device driver for which I want to start working. Maybe because it is in the newer version.

The solution to the above problem is to cross-compile. 
I see various tutorials out there but not able to find some similar one.
So any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify which image and which kernel you are running.

Please note that you can easily install a newer kernel:

https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Kernel_Options

Also you can build a newer kernel from sources using RCN's handy scripts:

https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-LinuxKernel

**Note that the first option is a lot easier and highly recommended for people who are not very well familiar with embedded Linux**